# Datagridview Sends Text Instead of Value to Update for Combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Datagridview bound to a DataSet (a view from my database). In my update function i define an UpdateCommand which takes all the columns and sends them to parameters in the database. Like this:

```
UPDATE       Data.DealDetails
SET                MoveFromID = @MOVEFROM, ProductID = @PRODUCT, MoveToID = @MOVETO,         ScheduledVolume = @VOL, TransportID = @TRANS, 
                     ScheduledDate = @DATE
WHERE        (DetailNo = @DETAILNO) AND (DealID = @DEAL)
```

So i map that to my database columns and everything works fine until i bind a dataset to a combobox cell in my datagrid view. In that case, i have a display member (A DESC) and an ID, i obviously need to send the ID to the database and therefore set that column as an INT. The problem arises when i actually call my update function. Tt (rightfully) throws an error because it cant translate a string into an int (most likely because it looks at the combobox's text and not the value). Now if i select a value from the dropdown and click another cell, the *value member* is displayed and the update runs fine.

**My Question:**

How do i send the *value* of a datagridviewcell to the update function instead of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think this can be done completely in the designer ... assuming you have your datagridview bound to your dataset and the name of the main table as datagridview.DataMember ... then you can do something like this (assuming the combobox column is the third column in your grid):

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[2]);
cb.DataSource = dataSet1.Lookup;
cb.ValueMember = "Id";
cb.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

the update command of the generated dataadapter works out of the box then (I tried with a simple example) ...

Answer (score 0):

PrfctByDsgn gave a good response, but ultimately i figured out the problem was that i caught the DataError event just to silence it (that will learn me) which screwed with the combobox's. I got the error in the first place because my View was sending in string values into the combobox instead of numeric values that it requires.